# Do $A$ and $A^T A$ share an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been learning about singular value decomposition from http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-svd and they say that orthongoal vectors in the domain are mapped to orthogonal vectors in the co-domain. For the 2D case we can image a sphere being deformed by a matrix transformation to an ellipse. Then these domain vectors paticularly map to the major and minor axis of the ellipse.

These vectors in the domain turn out to be the eigenvectors of $A^T A$. Should'nt the eigenvector of A with the highest eigenvalue be the vector that is turned to the major axis of the ellipse? As it is stretched the most of any vector it would be the major axis of the ellipse I suppose. In this case that vector must be an eigenvector of $A$ and $A^T A$. The other eigenvector may not be transformed to the minor axis due to the angle it makes with this one. Can someone verify or expand upon my intution?

Comment: Try some simple examples like $A=\pmatrix{2&1\\0&1}$ to find counter-examples to the claim.

Comment: I was looking to understand why the claim may be wrong. The argument seems to make sense to me

Comment: The SVD is related to the eigen-decomposition of the symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{0&A\\A^T&0}$, which is different enough that there are no direct connections. Also, in a wider sense, the transpose matrix is the adjoint matrix relative to a scalar product (the Euclidean as default). Your claim thus would have to be valid for all $A^TSA$ with $S$ symmetric positive definite.

Comment: While I digest that lets take a simple example. Say my two eigenvectors are $v_1$ and $v_2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Say $\lambda_1=100$ and  $\lambda_2=3$. Now if I apply this transform to the unit sphere won't $v_1$ be the vector stretched the most making it the major-axis of the ellipse?

Answer (score 3):

> As it is stretched the most of any vector it would be the major axis of the ellipse I suppose.

Huh, why? The matrix $A$ may not possess any eigenvector in the first place. Even if it has a real and complete eigenbasis, the eigenvector corresponding to the largest-sized eigenvalue is stretched the most by $A$ **only among all eigenvectors**, but it can happen that some other vector that is **not** an eigenvector is stretched even further.

For instance, suppose $A=\pmatrix{\epsilon_1&1\\ 0&\epsilon_2}$  for some very small $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2>0$. Let $e_1=(1,0)^T$ and $e_2=(0,1)^T$. Then the eigenvector corresponding to the largest-sized eigenvalue is $e_1$ but $\|Ae_1\|=\epsilon_1\ll1\approx\|Ae_2\|$.

In general, the vector that is stretched the most by $A$ is a singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value, not an eigenvector corresponding to the largest-sized eigenvalue. The largest singular value of $A$ is always bounded below by (and is often strictly greater than) the spectral radius of $A$. In fact, $\|A\|\ge\rho(A)$ for every submultiplicative matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$, including the induced $2$-norm $\|A\|_2=\sigma_1(A)$.

From another perspective, if $A$ and $A^TA$ share an eigenvector for some *nonzero* eigenvalue, $A$ and $A^T$ must share the same eigenvector as well. In fact, if $Av=\lambda v\ne0$ and $A^TAv=\mu v$, then
$$
A^Tv=A^T\left(\frac1\lambda Av\right)=\frac1\lambda A^TAv=\frac{\mu}{\lambda}v.
$$
Yet, there is no reason to believe that $A^T$ and $A$ in general will share any eigenvector at all. E.g. if
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ &&&1},
$$
then the only eigenspace of $A$ is the span of $(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ but the only eigenspace of $A^T$ is the span of $(0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. (This counterexample actually works over any field, not just $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: Yes this video shows that as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs2sRvSzA3o . But I thought so beacuse repeated application of a transform on any vectors makes that vector converge to its largest eigenvalue vector. If the eigenvector is not the one stretched the most then why do we consider vector associated with the largest singular values as the best approximation?